# Line not appearing under active/current navigation link

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to add a small, white line under my current/active navigation links; however, I am very unsure on how to add this feature to my links. I have the CSS properties for the white line, but I am struggling to actually add it to my current/active link.

This is the CSS for the "active" link, which is not doing anything. I just want the small, white line to appear underneath the current/active link:

```css
a.active::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  background-color: #7f1146;
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 11%;
  margin: 13px auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="active" href="About.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="Treatments.html">TREATMENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="/work/">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
  <li><a href="/clients/">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you still wanting to keep the original blue line and put the white line  underneath the blue?

Comment: No blue line, just a white line like in my CSS property, which is not an underline.

Comment: I just want a line to appear under the current/active navigation text, which is not a a   text-decoration: underline.

Comment: so you just want to slide the line under your link, correct?

Comment: Yeah, the current/active one, so the user knows which link they are currently on.